# Converting existing js Api to async/await

Tags: async-await, ecmascript-2017

Let us assume for a moment that I have an already existing API and wish to convert it to async/await style promises.

An example call of the API would be

```
Example.call(a,b,function(err,res){
    console.log(res);
});
```

Could someone please provide any ideas on how I can convert it to async/await.

Comment: Why would you want to convert it in the first place?

Comment: Because I will escape callback hell.

Comment: by adding async to an API that doesn't need it? care to explain your logic a bit more?

Comment: To clarify,the api is already async but is written in an "archaic" fashion. I would like to employ something more modern (syntactic sugar) by using the async await syntax.

Comment: ah I see, well sorry to bother you then. I don't believe in fixing something that's not broken :P

Comment: `async/await` is not part of ES7 (ES2016). It's also unclear to me what exactly you want to change. Do you want to change the implementation of `Example.call` or do you want to provide a wrapper around `Example.all` that uses `async/await`?